# how to setup copy activity for json in Azure Data Factory v2 schema not detected

Tags: azure-data-factory

i have try to read Json file using copy activity and write data in sql server.

my json file available in blob store.

i have set  file fromat-JSON format

> when i try to import schema i got error-Error occurred when
>   deserializing source JSON data. Please check if the data is in valid
>   JSON object format.. Activity ID:2f799221-f037-4f72-8e6c-385778929110

myjsonData

```
{
    "id": "ed0e4960-d9c5-11e6-85dc-d7996816aad3",
    "context": {
        "device": {
            "type": "PC"
        },
        "custom": {
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "TargetResourceType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                },
                {
                    "ResourceManagementProcessRunId": "827f8aaa-ab72-437c-ba48-d8917a7336a3"
                },
                {
                    "OccurrenceTime": "1/13/2017 11:24:37 AM"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Manish

Comment: Not sure what the format of rows in sql server you want, since your source data is nested json.

Comment: Hi,any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and your sample source data, you could import the schema directly,however the column is nested.

[image]

If you want to flatten the nested json before you store them into sql server database as rows,you could execute [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) before the Copy Activity.

Or you could execute the [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) in sql server dataset.